# Getting Drive SDK and DocsList to run side by side

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been fighting with this for over a month now and have reached my whits end.  The use case is this:

1 - When my client has a new file for one of his clients, he puts it in a folder on his Google drive account.  That folder is shared with his clients.  Since Google has no mechanism to automatically notify someone that a file in a folder thats shared with them has changed, I had to write one.  So I have a GAE/GWT app with a button, Notify.  That app has a button that scans his client folder and if there are new files in that folder, it grabs the email addresses of the people that folder is shared with and sends them an email saying they have new files.

2 - Periodically he needs to send mass emails to all of his clients.  So on his dashboard is a second button, he formats the email and clicks the button and the scanner goes to all of the client folders and compiles a list of all the people that folders are shared with.  Then loops the list and sends the emails.

The Drive SDK part was easy enough.  Until I hit the wall that the people a folder is shared with is available, but not their emails.  So I began trying to use the older API DocsService in conjunction with Drive SDK so I can get the email addresses.  I combed thru the sample applications and I found a utility class that sorta does what I want, here it is:

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

```
package com.voice.mailer.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppEngineCredentialStore;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService;

/**
 * Utility class for JDO persistence, OAuth flow helpers, and others.
 * 
 * @author Yaniv Inbar
 */
class Utils {

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new UrlFetchTransport();
    static Credential credential = null;
    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    private static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = null;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName());

    static GoogleClientSecrets getClientCredential() throws IOException {
        if (clientSecrets == null) {
            clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                    Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
            Preconditions
                    .checkArgument(
                            !clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId()
                                    .startsWith("Enter ")
                                    && !clientSecrets.getDetails()
                                            .getClientSecret()
                                            .startsWith("Enter "),
                            "Download client_secrets.json file from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=calendar "
                                    + "into calendar-appengine-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
        }
        return clientSecrets;
    }

    static String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) {
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
        url.setRawPath("/oauth2callback");
        return url.build();
    }

    static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow newFlow() throws IOException {
        HashSet<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
        s.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
        s.add("https://docs.google.com/feeds/");
        s.add("https://docs.googleusercontent.com/");
        s.add("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
        s.add("http://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest");
        s.add("http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007");
        s.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo");

        return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                JSON_FACTORY, getClientCredential(), s)
                .setCredentialStore(new AppEngineCredentialStore())
                .setAccessType("offline").build();

        // http(s)://docs.google.com/feeds/
    }

    static Drive loadDriveClient() throws IOException {

        if (credential == null) {
            String userId = UserServiceFactory.getUserService()
                    .getCurrentUser().getUserId();
            credential = newFlow().loadCredential(userId);
        }
        return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .build();
    }

    static DocsService loadDocsService(String applicationName) {

        if (credential == null) {
            String userId = UserServiceFactory.getUserService()
                    .getCurrentUser().getUserId();
            try {
                credential = newFlow().loadCredential(userId);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        DocsService service = new DocsService(applicationName);

        log.info("token: " + credential.getAccessToken());

        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        // service.setHeader("Authorization",
        // "Bearer " + credential.getAccessToken());

        return service;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an {@link IOException} (but not a subclass) in order to work
     * around restrictive GWT serialization policy.
     */
    static IOException wrappedIOException(IOException e) {
        if (e.getClass() == IOException.class) {
            return e;
        }
        return new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }

    private Utils() {
    }
}
```

now this class handles the Drive SDK part great, im able to call the the loadDriveClient method and I get a class thats ready to rock and roll.  But when I call the loadDocsService and call a method, I keep getting the following error:

```
 10, 2013 5:36:07 PM com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector handleResponse
WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {authsub=WWW-Authenticate: AuthSub realm="http://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest"}
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: OK
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:570)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:652)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at com.voice.mailer.shared.DocumentList.getAclFeed(DocumentList.java:611)
    at com.voice.mailer.server.NewFileProcessorImpl.processNewFiles(NewFileProcessorImpl.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Mar 10, 2013 5:36:21 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$PersistDatastore persist
INFO: Time to persist datastore: 6 ms
```

I have tried everything I can think of and every example I can find.  I have no idea why its not creating the DocsService correctly.  Can you give me any ideas as to why this isn't working?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have

> https://docs.google.com/feeds/

as part of your OAuth scope.

Comment: In the method newFlow() above, that scope is already listed.  That was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: How about adding the Drive SDK scope together with the Documents List scope?

Comment: look at my class, thats exactly what I did.

Comment: Can you use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`?

Comment: i can try it, but what does that have to do with DocsList?  I think my problem is that the way I wrote it, the docs list can't see the credential token at all for some reason.  I don't think the error has anything to do with the scope.

Comment: Now that I've looked at it a bit more closely, it seems that it's using AuthSub instead of OAuth2 (and the token is for OAuth2). I'm not familiar with their Java library so I don't know for sure. Try playing around in their playground at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to see if the issue lies in the use of their Java library and not really the API itself.